# deny all folder except some php files

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

I have a script for set some limitation on download host.
this script give me some file`(index.php|dl.php|config.php)` that I have to put them on my download host.
The script also has these htaccess codes:

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from All

<FilesMatch "^(index\.php)?$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^(dl\.php)?$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```

but my web server is NGINX. what rewrite code should I put in nginx.conf ?
 by the way, I'd like set limitation on `vip` folder `mysomain.com/vip` . and I put (index.php|dl.php|config.php)` on it.

Comment: Add all the information to the question (including your comment below) and add what you have already tried

Comment: @Drifter104  I did it.tnx

Answer (score 1):

I used it and it finally works.

```
location ~ ^(index\.php)?$ {
allow all;
}
location ~ ^(dl\.php)?$ {
allow all;
}
location /vip {
    deny all;
}
```

PS: I had some problems with these codes again. So I changed them to:

```
error_page 500 /index.php?error=500;
error_page 404 /index.php?error=404;
error_page 403 /index.php?error=403;
location /vip {
  internal;
  alias /home/mydirecadmin ACC /domains/dl1.mydomain.com/public_html/vip;
}
```

But I want to know, is it secure? how can I set a restriction for all files and folders within the VIP folder except dl and index.php?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Although this protects the `/vip` directory, it doesn't appear to do the same as the `.htaccess` code you posted. The `.htaccess` code blocks _all_ files except for the two exceptions. In the Nginx code, the first two `location` blocks look superfluous?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms and check exactly how nginx will match the locations. This might break other things for you

Comment: You don't need the parentheses in your `location` regex matches, since you aren't using them anywhere. So you should use `location ~ ^index.php$` instead.

Comment: @w3dk can you convert my htaccess to nginx code? how can I protect VIP folder except dl and index?